# \citeauthor with LNCS template raises undefined control sequence error

Tags: citing, templates

I am writing a conference paper in which I am to use the [LNCS template](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines). The problem is I cannot use `\citeauthor` to refer to the authors of a certain paper, and it is tedious and pointless to manually write and maintain the (sometimes foreign) names of researchers especially in the Related Work section when an automatic mechanism already exists..

On top of that, in the template (file `splncs04.bst`) it is explicitly stated that:

> Note that this file will not work for author-year style citations.

Is there a way to get a similar functionality to `\citeauthor` without risking a rejection of the paper?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You've been informed that you must use a bibliography style (`splncs04`) which generates only numeric-style citation call-outs. To learn what the penalties for disregarding this requirement may be, you should really quuery the conference organizer(s) directly.

Comment: Thank you @Mico for the response. Regardless of the formal requirements then, are you hinting that there is no technical way to get `\citeauthor` up and running with such a citation constraint?

Comment: It is my very strong impression that one of the main purposes of numeric-style citation call-outs is to the economize as much as possible on space dedicated to citation call-outs. Spelling out authors’ names runs directly counter to this purpose. However, as I wrote earlier, you really really need to check with the publisher regarding which deviations (if any!) from the pure numeric citation style they will accept,

Answer (score 1):

I think your can use this `splncs04nat.bst` from [here](https://github.com/tpavlic/splncs04nat)!

The resulting `splncs04nat.bst` emulates the `splncs04.bst` from Springer; however, `splncs04nat.bst` is `natbib` compatible.

Finally, `\citet{xxx}` will get `xxx et al. [number]`.